# Set the default DateTimeOffset value?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have the following model class for entity framework code-first. I want to set the default value current time for `CreateTime` when creating database table. However, the following code cannot be compiled because

> The type 'System.DateTimeOffset' cannot be declared const

Is it a better way to set default value for `DateTimeOffset`?

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(now)]
    public DateTimeOffset CreateTime 
    { 
        get { return _createTime; } 
        set { _createTime = value; } 
    }

    private const DateTimeOffset now = DateTimeOffset.Now;
    private DateTimeOffset _createTime = now;
}
```

Comment: Are you deliberately trying to "freeze" `now` to the moment it was set?

Comment: `DateTimeOffset` is a `DateTime` with an `Offset` property. You can't use it with `const` because mostly _primitive types_ can be used with it. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9e7f1929-9ea2-487c-a037-628dc3c4fb38/the-type-systemdatetime-cannot-be-declared-const

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way for doing what you need is to override `SaveChanges` method in your `DbContext`.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries<MyClass>().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added))
        {
            entry.Entity.CreateTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: How about just use the following code in the class? `public DateTimeOffset CreateTime { get { return _createTime; } set { _createTime = value; } }

        private DateTimeOffset _createTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;`?

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 Theoretically it can take ages before a class is saved after it was constructed. Remember that `_createTime` does not change after the value is set.